# How to get user input in ORACLE using ACCEPT?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get input from user in runtime in ORACLE. I am trying to do this.

1. Get input 'name' from user
2. Greet user with 'name' using DBMS_OUTPUT

My code so far:

```
ACCEPT name PROMPT 'Your name:'

declare 
      a varchar2(10);
begin
      a := '&x';  
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the name you assigned in the ACCEPT statement in your code. So

```
ACCEPT name PROMPT 'Your name:'

begin
      dbms_output.put_line ('Hello &name !');  
end; 
/
```

---

Regarding your comment:

> "ACCEPT name PROMPT 'Your name:' still is a unsuported command"

According to your comment you're using Oracle's LiveSQL, right? Well, `accept` is a SQL*Plus command for handling input parameters; SQL*Plus is part of a client install. LiveSQL is a different client. If you read [its FAQs](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:HELP:100390468870258::LEVEL1:::) you will see:

> **Can I use input parameters?**
>
> No, we do not support input parameters at runtime.

Comment: For line 1 :Unsupported Command
For line 2: ORA-06550: line 2, column 19: PLS-00321: expression 'PUT_LINE' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement

Comment: its okay .  ACCEPT name PROMPT 'Your name:' still is a unsuported command